# How does rendezvous work?

Tags: ada

I am studying for an exam and am having a difficult time understanding Rendezvous.
Here's an example I'm looking a

```
While(1) {
 select{
  when a == TRUE :
   accept A() {f1; b=FALSE}
  when b == TRUE :
   accept B() {f2; a=FALSE}
  else {a=true; b=true}
 }
}
```

The following calls arrive in the given order:
A(), B(), B(), A(), A(), B()

In which order will the calls be accepted? And can caller of A or B starve?

I'd really appreciate any help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Even if this *were* Ada code (it is not. Ada doesn't use curly braces, or a `==` operator, and the language is case-insensitive, so `a` and `A` would be the same thing), the way I'm reading it I don't think the question could be answered without knowing the initial state of your two boolean flags (guards, I'm guessing). Are you sure this isn't something like Concurrent C?

Answer (score 6):

That's not Ada. At all.

For some guidance on tasking with actual Ada read Chapter 14 of [Ada Distilled](http://www.sigada.org/education/pages/Ada-Distilled-07-27-2003-Color-Version.pdf).

And to be honest, if you didn't recognize your example as not Ada, you probably ought to start with Chapter 1.

Answer (score 4):

Going with the logic of your problem rather than the syntax, I think the answer is 'it all depends'.

The task that's running this loop (call it `Server`) is in a busy loop (most times round the loop, it'll end up setting `A := True; B := True;`). This could use up all your CPU and starve the other tasks out.

Assuming that doesn't happen and you have 2 client tasks `A_Caller` and `B_Caller` which have higher priority than `Server` and call their entries relatively infrequently, then you might get

1. `A_Caller` and `B_Caller` both run and call their respective entries.
2. `Server` enters the `select` and finds both guards open and the entries called; it chooses to accept `A` (it could have chosen `B`). The guard `B` is closed.
3. Next time round the loop, guard `A` is open but there is no caller; guard `B` is closed; the `else` part is chosen, so guard `B` is opened.
4. Next time round the loop, `Server` accepts `B`; guard `A` is closed.
5. Next time round the loop, guard `B` is open but there is no caller; the `else` part is chosen, so guard `A` is opened.
6. Next time round the loop, both guards are open but there is no caller, so the `else` part is chosen again and away we spin.

Obviously the exact sequence followed will depend on when the entry calls arrive with respect to `Server`'s loop. Assuming the entry calls in your question happen a second apart, the entries will be accepted in the order called.

I don't think you can get starvation unless one of the callers is running sufficiently frequently that it's called its entry again before `Server` has got back round its loop. It would be hard to get this to happen under a general-purpose OS.

Answer (score 2):

This does not look like ada syntax, Perhaps you could repost with ada code?
Meanwhile i refer you to: http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Ada_Programming/Tasking#Rendezvous